# How to write Filters to a Text Box in a Dashboard?

Tags: tableau-api

I have a text which I would like to add the week filters to it. The week filter is across all the worksheets in the dashboard. I am not using the title of the worksheets but text boxes instead. How can I populate the Text Box with the filter value?

[image]

Comment: can you add image of what you need?

Comment: Pic added. Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't be done. Floating Text/Filter next to each other is the alternative